# wordpress login session to another CMS?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, session

Is it possible to get the and store the login session from a wordpress login and then to use it to 'login' to another cms without having to click the login button there?
I already managed to copy the username database from wordpress to my sub cms system, but i don't know how to copy the login session, so now the user has to click login on the sub cms and then use his login details made in wordpress. How to automatically log him in as he already has an account in wordpress and the sub cms ? Is that even possible just with cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress REST API and register a specific route for your purpose. After that set jwt or other methods to check if a user is authenticated to the WordPress backend.

you can find more at: [Login a WP user via REST API](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/login-a-wp-user-via-rest-api/)